# Running test suite from both terminal using pytest and unittest runner but show only unittest runner results and execute once

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, pytest

i am trying to execute my following test suite:

```
import unittest
from Login_Page import LoginPageAndLogout


def test_suite():
    # get all tests from classes
    login_test = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(LoginPageAndLogout)

    # create a test suite
    all_tests = unittest.TestSuite([
        login_test
    ])

    # run the suite
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(all_tests)
```

from Pycharm's terminal using the command :

```
sudo pytest selenium-tests/testSuite.py -vvv -s
```

and a part of the output is the following:

```
============================================================================================================ test session starts ============================================================================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.14, pytest-3.1.3, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0 -- /usr/bin/python
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /home/osboxes/PycharmProjects/WebTesting, inifile:
plugins: cov-2.5.1
collected 3 items 

selenium-tests/testSuite.py::LoginPageAndLogout::test_failed_login <- selenium-tests/Login_Page.py PASSED
selenium-tests/testSuite.py::LoginPageAndLogout::test_login <- selenium-tests/Login_Page.py FAILED
selenium-tests/testSuite.py::test_suite test_failed_login (Login_Page.LoginPageAndLogout) ... ok
test_login (Login_Page.LoginPageAndLogout) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 55.993s
```

The structure of my `Login_Page.py` file is:

```
class LoginPageAndLogout(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # ...

    # login with incorrect credentials to get error message
    def test_failed_login(self):
        # ...

    # login with correct credentials
    def test_login(self):
        # ...

    def tearDown(self):
        # ...
```

As you can see from the output, I have 2 tests but the terminal collects three things instead and run each test twice. Is there a way to execute only the `PASSED/FAILED` execution, not the `... ok` ?

If I comment out `unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(all_tests)` my tests executed only once but I get the `... ok` result instead of the `PASSED/FAILED` which is the one I want; so I see the `pytest` execution results instead of the unittests runner results.

How can I run from the terminal my suite using the unitest runner only?

Comment: Because you are executing `unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(all_tests)`? You are basically invoking `pytest` and `unittest` runner, both executing the tests once, thus the duplicated output.

Comment: @hoefling thank you for your answer. if I comment the `unittest.TextTestRunner ...` command, my tests are executed only once. but i don't want the ` ... ok` display for the results, i prefer the `PASSED/FAILED` from the unittest. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not just run the selected tests with `pytest` from command line? `pytest selenium-tests/Login_Page.py` is equivalent to running the `testSuite.py`.

Comment: @hoefling I wanted to run all my tests at once, and running through terminal it may caused to forget running some of them as there are more than 20 test scripts.   But of course, if i want to run just a single test I run it individually as you suggested.. i have commented the `all tests = unittest.TestSuite([ ... ])` and the `unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(all_tests)` and I just run this testSuite from the terminal as before `sudo pytest testSuite.py -vvv -s` and now I get only the `PASSED/FAILLED ` results I wanted for all my scripts, all at once. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was quite easy as I had just misunderstood how my unit test was being executed all this time.

The only thing I had to do was to comment out the whole `test_suite` class from my `testSuite.py` file and just import at the top of this file the classes from the test scripts i wanted to execute.

Now my tests run only once and I can still execute all my scripts all at once without typing them in my command one by one using the exact same command:
`sudo pytest selenium-tests/testSuite.py -vvv -s`

The output of that command is now:

```
osboxes@osboxes:~/PycharmProjects/WebTesting$ sudo pytest selenium-tests/testSuite.py -vvv -s
========================================================================================================================= test session starts ==========================================================================================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.14, pytest-3.1.3, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0 -- /usr/bin/python
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /home/osboxes/PycharmProjects/WebTesting, inifile:
plugins: cov-2.5.1
collected 2 items 

selenium-tests/testSuite.py::LoginPageAndLogout::test_failed_login <- selenium-tests/Login_Page.py PASSED
selenium-tests/testSuite.py::LoginPageAndLogout::test_login <- selenium-tests/Login_Page.py PASSED

====================================================================================================================== 2 passed in 58.81 seconds =======================================================================================================================
osboxes@osboxes:~/PycharmProjects/WebTesting$
```